# Monaco editor prevent line decorations from expanding

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, monaco-editor

**My objective is to instantiate a Monaco editor line decoration that does not expand to the lower rows when I hit enter at the end of the created decoration.**

For example, when I create a Monaco editor(in React) and instantiate a line decoration with the following code:
`js

```
import { createStyles } from "@mantine/styles";
import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react";
import monaco from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

const DecoratedEditor = () => {
    const { classes } = useStyles();

    const [code, setCode] = useState(`#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//press enter on my end to see decoration expand

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}`);

    const editorRef = useRef<monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor | null>(null);

    return (
        <Editor
            value={code}
            language="cpp"
            theme="vs-dark"
            onChange={(newValue) => {
                if (!newValue) return;
                setCode(newValue);
            }}
            beforeMount={(monaco) => {}}
            onMount={(editor, monaco) => {
                editorRef.current = editor;

                editor.getModel()?.deltaDecorations(
                    [],
                    [
                        {
                            range: new monaco.Range(4, 1, 4, 47),
                            options: {
                                inlineClassName: classes.lineDecoration,
                            },
                        },
                    ]
                );
            }}
            height={400}
        />
    );
};
export default DecoratedEditor;

const useStyles = createStyles((theme) => {
    return {
        lineDecoration: {
            width: "10px !important ",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.4)",
        },
    };
});
```

I get the following output: [Normal editor with normal decoration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9whsb.png)

But, if I press "Enter" at the end of the decoration at line 4 and write on the following line I get this: [New decoration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liAFK.png)

Is there a way to prevent the decoration from expanding itself? Thank you.

I already searched for options in Monaco editor documentation to prevent this from happening, but I didn't find out anythigh that could satisfy my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been there.

It would help you get the job done as well.

That is

```
stickiness: 1
```

In you case, you can add one more option to the list.

```
options: {
    inlineClassName: classes.lineDecoration,
    stickiness: 1
}
```

stickness 1 is `AlwaysGrowsWhenTypingAtEdges`

```
/**
* Describes the behavior of decorations when typing/editing near their edges.
* Note: Please do not edit the values, as they very carefully match `DecorationRangeBehavior`
*/

export enum TrackedRangeStickiness {
     AlwaysGrowsWhenTypingAtEdges = 0,
     NeverGrowsWhenTypingAtEdges = 1,
     GrowsOnlyWhenTypingBefore = 2,
     GrowsOnlyWhenTypingAfter = 3
}
```

In case, a code snippet goes like this (you can use it as you would like) :

```
decorations = editor.deltaDecorations([],
            [
                {
                    range: new monaco.Range(1, 1, 4, 4),
                    options: {
                        stickiness: 1,  // NeverGrowsWhenTypingAtEdges
                    }
                }
            ])
        }
```